# TFS 2008: How do I setup the Alert functionality?

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

The alerts that I setup for source code changes isn't being triggered. I suspect that the email server settings are wrong, but where would I configure them?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you're looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms400808.aspx

Comment: Close, but that is for TFS 2010. TSF 2008 doesn't seem to have that command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change these two files:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services\Web.config

```
<appSettings>
...
<add key="smtpServer" value="mySmtpServer" />
```

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team System Web Access\Web\web.config

```
 <webAccessSettings>
    ...
    <emailSettings sendingEmailEnabled="true" />
...
</webAccessSettings>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="fromaddress@domain.com">
<network host="mySmtpServer" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"  .... />
....
```

There's good blog post on the topic [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2008/06/13/team-foundation-server-tfs-2008-and-authenticated-smtp.aspx)